# Error hresult :80004001 , message : Command execution failed. Not implemented

Tags: iis, cmd

I ran the command "`%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list requests /elapsed:1000`" in the server and encountered the following error:

> Error < hresult :80004001 , message : Command execution failed. Not
>   implemented

Comment: Could anyone help me what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Looks like there are certain IIS features not included when it was setup.

```
Right Click on My Computer and Select Manage.This will open Server Manager
Select Manage and Choose Add Roles/Features 
Select Installation Type Role-Based/ feature based installation,Click next
Select server,Click next
Select server roles and you should see Web Server(IIS)->Web Server->Health and Diagnostics 
Check Request Monitor and tracing
```

[image]